# Why email is not receving if sent successfully using nodemailer in node js?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

// transporter object
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587, 
    secure: false, // true then port will change
    requireTLS:true,
    auth: {
        user: "mygmail@gmail.com", 
        pass:"myapppassword" //google app password
    }
})

// mail object
const mailOptions = {
    name:"hello",
    from: "my@gmail.com",
    to: "myfriend@gmail.com", //allowed comma separated mutiple emails
    subject: "Node js mail text",

    text: "hello buddy aapke father aaye hain!"
}

// send mail
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(res.response)
    }
})
```

In the above code snippet i tried send text email to another account and it is sent successfully but i am not receiving the email but when i try to send the email to the same email it is getting inside the inbox , why it is happening ? Thank you